# Pygame Collisions Are Only Working on One Object

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I'm coding a platformer on pygame, and I've got a problem where only one of my platform's collisions are being detected.

This is for my final in Computer Science course. I've tried using group collision but that only works with sprites, and if I wanted to go down that route I'd have to rewrite quite a bit of my code.

```py
# in main loop
for i in platforms: 
    if i.rect.colliderect(c) and c.isjump == False: 
        # If player is on platform and not jumping
        c.falling = False 
        c.isjump = False
        c.jumpcount = 10
        c.onplat = True
    else:
        c.falling = True
        c.onplat = False
```

Everything here works (and does not produce any errors), except when I test it, only one platform stops the player from falling while the other(s) just phase through the player. I can show more of the code if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've identified a platform, which "stops" the player, then you've to `break` the loop:

```py
for i in platforms: 
    if i.rect.colliderect(c) and c.isjump == False: 
       c.falling = False 
       c.isjump = False
       c.jumpcount = 10
       c.onplat = True

       break # <----- break the loop

    else:
       c.falling = True
       c.onplat = False
```

else the result of the next platform would overwrite the result and the last platform in the list set the result in any case.

Note you can simplify the code, by finding [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) platform:

```py
if c.isjump == False and any([i for i in platforms if i.rect.colliderect(c)]):
   c.falling = False 
   c.jumpcount = 10
   c.onplat = True
```